Java libraries built from source have differences to those published wrt to anonymous classes
I am trying to build groovy (and others) from source using the instructions in their help file.
https://github.com/apache/groovy/tree/GROOVY_3_0_21?tab=readme-ov-file
The built binaries operate just fine, but when I use pkgdiff to compare the binaries there are differences such as:

The source jars are identical, and I can see no anonymous class that match the issue reported. My only suspicion is that there is some jvm optimisation occuring. I am using Java 11 which I think is what Apache use for v3 stream. This issue does not seem confined to Groovy however, I've seen the same in CXF. I've also tried Java 9 with exact same issue. Thanks...

Yeah. That must be an optimization. If you look at the source (here), one of those is capturing a reference to the outer "GPathResult" and the other isn't. If you inspect the source, the outer reference isn't needed. The left-hand one is probably more correct. The right-hand one will prevent a GPathResult from being GC-d if you hold a reference to the iterator. Since iterators are only used once, it probably makes no difference in practice

Their snapshots are building in GitHub Actions with Azul Zulu 11.0.6 (https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_3_0_21/.github/workflows/gradle-snapshot-distribution.yml#L26), so if you're intent on getting them to match, I'd start with matching that. I don't see any workflow for releases, so it's possible it's even released locally... At that point, all bets are off. The compiler version might even change from version to version, especially if its done on different machines. Could even use the Eclipse compiler, which is a totally separate implementation.

@Michael Great thanks, stick this as an answer and I'll tick it. Also particularly helpful pointer to the JVM they use.

You're seeing Java Compiler (javac) syntax sugar in action.
How does Java deal with inner classes?
When you write this example code:
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        System.out.println("I was created at " + x);
      }
    };
    r.run();
  }
}

We're seeing the concept of 'anonymous inner classes' in action:

In java-the-language you may create class definitions inside methods themselves.
In fact, you don't even have to name them. The above is creating a method definition with a name chosen by javac (that's why you end up seeing that $6 in your screenshot; it is part of the name; javac picked it; it is a name that does not clash with any other name), and then immediately constructing a new instance of this class you just defined.

However, in java-the-class-file-format, this does not exist. At all.
So javac has to fake it. It does this by creating a package private top level class (because 'top level class', as in, not an 'inner class', is the only thing class file formats can contain), marking it as synthetic (which is a flag that java-the-virtual-machine completely ignores, but javac (the compiler) treats synthetic members as if they do not exist at all - this way, you can't try to refer to Foobar$6 and treat it as a real class. It is a real class, but javac acts as if it does not exist because its synthetic flag is set).
In other words, javac compiles the above as:
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Runnable r = new Test$6();
    r.run();
  }
}

class Test$6 implements Runnable {
  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println("I was created at " + x);
  }
}

Except, now there's a problem. The above doesn't actually work - the code in Test$6 refers to x, but x isn't available there.
The local variable is captured (also called 'enclosed' - this is why x -> (); syntax is sometimes called 'closures') by the inner code; javac needs to fake the 'transfer' of that x variable too!
And it does that with the constructor. So, javac actually desugars our original snippet into this:
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Runnable r = new Test$6(x);
    r.run();
  }
}

class Test$6 implements Runnable {
  private final long x;

  Test$6(long x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println("I was created at " + x);
  }
}

Why am I seeing this difference?
The key clue in the above explanation is that javac itself determines which variables from the 'enclosing scope' are 'captured' by the method local class definition and sets up the transport of those to the instance by way of making a constructor for it. The difference you are seeing is a difference in javac's determination of which variables are captured. In the code you compiled, javac determined that 2 variables are captured. We don't know what they are, we do know that the first one is of type GPathResult (probably 'this'), and the second is of type Object. Whereas the compiled code you downloaded determined that zero variables are captured.
Except that's not actually true - if you look at your downloaded version, it still has the fields for those 2 types - a field named this$0 and a field named val$obj.
As written, the left side is bizarre - you have 2 final fields and a constructor that takes no args. Constructors have to set their final fields so pray tell - what are they?
However, one weird detail, final fields are kinda a fake thing too - javac ensures final fields are written to exactly once, but java-the-virtual-machine doesn't care nearly as much about it. They could be set later, final notwithstanding.
Your next steps

Compile with different (newer) versions of javac and rerun your comparison.
(If you want to know how this works and get to the bottom of it) Use javap -v -c to show the actual code of all the methods in GPathResult$6. Find where those fields of $6 are used, and where they are set. That'll provide some clues.
(If you just want the differences to go away without understanding why this is happening) update your question to include the exact version of javac you are using along with your --release parameter (or if you are using those, -source and -target, which are the old versions of release), and check the class file version id of the downloaded class files, as well as paste the build script as it was when that version was created (I would assume groovy has a source control repo of some stripe and that it has tags for releases. Go to the right tag, check the pom.xml or build.xml or gradle.build or whatever).


Yes thanks I realise this. Doesn't answer my question. But thanks for response.

@visionset If you know all this, you also knew the next steps. Why didn't you do them? It's a bit disrespectful to ask a question if you already know what relatively simple steps you can take to move much closer to an answer and couldn't be bothered to do them? I made some assumptions based on the notion you didn't take those steps - that you didn't know what was happening and hence where to go next.

Sorry, reread you answer and it is actually helpful
